# Swift Unit Test how to set with a private setter

Tags: swift, unit-testing, access-control, private-members

Here is a little background:

I am trying to test some functions. I CANNOT change anything in the function or any class variables.

So I am calling this function in my unit test, the problem is that, there is a boolean flag, this method simply will just not execute if this flag is not set to true. But this flag has a private setter, so I can directly set it.

I asked around someone told me to use a extension IN the test file to set the variable, but I've tried I don't think I can set it if the extension is not in the same file as the function. Am I doing something wrong? Or is there any other way to test it?

Comment: There is of course some logic to update this private property and it is this logic (function)  you need to use in your test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they were referring to is to place an extension in the file with the class-under-test. So if you have something like:

```
class ToBeTested {
    private(set) var bool: Bool
}
```

You can add an internal setter:

```
extension ToBeTested {
    func setBoolTrue() { bool = true }
}
```

But this has to be in the same file with `ToBeTested`. If you cannot modify that file, this is not a solvable problem. If it needs to be tested this way, then the class will need to be designed to permit that.

When a property is marked `private(set)`, the compiler can assume that the value cannot be changed in any way outside this file. That allows it to apply optimizations that may not be valid if the property were changeable outside this file. The "setter method" may not even exist if the compiler determines that it doesn't need it. For example, it may completely inline that operation, or eliminate it entirely if it can prove the value is never changed.

Comment: I can't modify that file. Is there some other way to test? like not directly testing by invoking this function.

Comment: It depends on the precise situation you have. For example, if this is an objc property, there are ways to manipulate it. But if it's pure Swift, and actually a boolean flag that must be true but you cannot in any way make true, then no, there's no solution. Something must change. If the problem is somewhat different than that, then yes, there might be a solution. But as described, there may not even be a property for you to modify. Swift is free to optimize out things it can prove can't happen.

Comment: If I can make the setter internal does that mean I can then access it within the extension in a different file?

Comment: If the setter is internal, it can be accessed anywhere in the current module (or in a module that imports it `@testable`). It doesn't matter if it's within an extension. `private` means the current declaration, or extensions to that declaration within this file. `fileprivate` means the current file. `internal` means this module. `public` means any module.

Comment: okay thanks I'll just try to see if I can change that to internal then